# Datetime plugins for PhoneGap + Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Since the HTML5 input type datetime/datetime-local/date/time is not supported for Android (also verified by testing them in a PhoneGap app) I am thinking about using one of the PhoneGap Datetime plugins (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins and search date).

Has anyone tried these, do they work and which one is the better alternative?

My requirements: I need a time (showing hours:minutes) and datetime picker that works in newer versions of Android. I need them to be customizable and adjust with respect to localization (24/12 hour, date format etc).

Comment: datetime is supported in Android starting from KitKat [(source)](http://caniuse.com/#search=datetime)

Comment: @Mister Smith using the time input in my PhoneGap app I was for example not able to set "step" attribute. Seconds would always show up no matter what I did. Clearly some things are not supported fully (I was using Android Kitkat).